# NIPDAU vs SN finishing and certification

Tags: pcb-design, components, certification

I am about to certify my design for RF and BT and I already have the mass production component reels. However the certification will be done with a prototype using spot purchased components. For one of the components there is a difference in the lead finish from NIPDAU to NIPDAU/SN. Is that something to worry about ?. It's by first time doing it and I am not sure.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "NIPDAU/SN" means that there are two manufacturing sites that use different lead finishes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only difference is the quality in production yields and long term aging of Pb-free solder finishes to avoid defects.  It will have no impact on certification.

NIPDAU/SN = NiPdAu over Sn  (Nickel Palladium Gold over Tin plating.

Since Gold (Au) is not soluble in Tin (Sn) or even tin-lead (SnPb), so the small amount of gold content from either pad or component can weaken the joint by creating elongated brittle crystals, which results in lower pull strengths.  The addition of Palladium (Pd) improves bonding of gold's corrosion resistance and Nickel's strength and results in faster solder wetting time.  The use of Organic Solderability Perservative (OSP) finishes on PCB's yields the highest solder pull-strength.

ref:
https://www.ti.com/lit/an/szza026/szza026.pdf
https://www.ti.com/lit/an/szza031/szza031.pdf